# How to filter atts for every shortcode in WordPress

Tags: shortcode, wordpress

I need to filter the `$atts` array for every shortcode (either every shortcode registered or just every shortcode in page) but can't find a way which also caters for situations in which the attribute names may not be known beforehand.

Example: `[shortcode known_attribute="value" 8c69f120="unknown attribute"]`

I tried by looping through `$GLOBALS['shortcode_tags']` and using the `shortcode_atts_{$shortcode}` filter but because `shortcode_atts` is a combination of `array_merge` and unset atts not in `$pairs` array, this won't work.

Does anyone know how to apply a filter to `$atts` for every shortcode in a way which caters for shortcodes for which attribute names cannot necessarily be known beforehand?

Comment: Are they all named `$atts`? Shortcodes often name this variable something else.

Comment: Good point. `$atts` is the name used in the documentation but that doesn't mean it always will be. I'll assume they are though; unless grabbing the first param of the shortcode function is possible (I don't think it is—at least I couldn't find a usable filter in `shortcode_atts`)

Comment: `$atts` is just a variable name

Comment: It is, but I think it's relatively safe to assume that most shortcodes will use that name as it's documented that way. As I said, the alternative would be grabbing the first param so feel free to propose an option that tries that! :)

Comment: The variable name does not matter, you can refer to it as `$attributes` or `$original_atts` or the like in filter callback functions.

Comment: Correct, you can call it whatever you like. You can also use [func_get_args](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) to get an array of all arguments, but I also need to be able to filter the values for every shortcode while keeping attributes with unknown names.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do exactly, but you can catch any attribute and modify (or unset) the corresponding output with something like the following:

```
foreach( array_keys( $GLOBALS['shortcode_tags'] ) as $tag ) {
    add_filter( "shortcode_atts_{$tag}", "so26932914_shortcode_atts", 25, 3 );
}

function so26932914_shortcode_atts( $out, $pairs, $atts )
{
    if( isset( $atts['foo'] ) && '' != $atts['foo'] )
        $out['foo'] = 'bar';

    return $out;
}
```

One important caveat: shortcodes are **not** required to define the third `$shortcode` parameter, which is essential for the `$shortcode_atts_{$shortcode}` filter to do its thing.

Comment: I don't think that'll work because the `shortcode_atts_{$shortcode}` filters are registered by calling `shortcode_atts` which would remove the unknown attributes. `/wp-includes/shortcodes.php:359`

Comment: OR am I wrong and the shortcode-specific filter does exist by virtue of the shortcode existing so it's not necessary for `shortcode_atts` to be used in the shortcode for your idea to work?

Comment: Codex quote: "If the $atts list has unsupported attributes, then they will be ignored and removed from the final returned list." I'm still not sure what you're trying to do; maybe you could iterate over the shortcodes using the filter dynamically like in the example, compare the `$pairs` an `$atts`, and save all non-matching entries (i.e. unsupported attributes) to an array?

Comment: That was my first though, but `shortcode_atts_{$shortcode}` only works for shortcodes which use `shortcode_atts` and if `shortcode_atts` removes unknown attributes then how do I get them back into the scope of the shortcode function?

Comment: By filtering again, this time with a lower priority (i.e. higher number), and adding stuff to `$out`? I don't see a solution for the missing third param..

Comment: or maybe you could deregister all shortcodes and register them again with the third param (value = key of the items in the `$GLOBALS['shortcode_tags']` array)?

Comment: But if the `shortcode_atts_{$tag}` filter runs as part of the `shortcode_atts` filter then how would that work for shortcodes which don't use that function?